# Can I overwrite an HTTP Server Variable in the .NET Request Object

Tags: .net, iis, query-string

I would like, at the very beginning of a page's lifecycle, to check for a value in the QUERY_STRING server variable, and replace it with another value.  Every subsequent request for the Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING") object would return my new value.

Is there any way of doing this, without having to re-code every place in the app that calls that variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`HttpContext.RewritePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath.aspx) to set a new query string.

It is not possible to rewrite the `Request.ServerVariables` or `Request.QueryString` collections directly.